# ¿Cómo hacer dos inserts a diferente tabla en mysql en una misma consulta?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

El problema que tengo es que quiero relacionar dos tablas, la tabla personas con la tabla coches y para hacer dicha relación muchos a muchos cree una tabla intermedia persona_has_coche, y cada que haga un registro a la tabla persona tengo que agregar un registro simultáneamente a la tabla persona_has_coche para ir llenando las tablas simultáneamente, al menos creo que así se hace si estoy mal agradecería que alguien me dijera.

Bueno en base a eso se me ocurrió hacer dos inserts simultáneos, ejemplo 
agrego a persona 1 automáticamente tengo que agregar un registro con relación a la persona 1 en persona_has_coche y pues haría otro insert seguido, pero como hago eso desde la consola de sql.

```
-- insert persona
INSERT INTO `mrp_uno`.`persona` (`idPersona`, `nombre`, `apellido`) VALUES 
('5', 'pedro', 'lopez');



-- insert persona_has_coche
INSERT INTO `mrp_uno`.`persona_has_coche` (`numeroCompra`, 
`Persona_idPersona`, `Coche_idCoche`) VALUES ('21', '5', '11');
```

en otras palabras y mas facil quiero hacer algo así

> INSERT INTO `mrp_uno`.`persona` (`idPersona`, `nombre`, `apellido`) VALUES ('5', 'pedro', 'lopez'), INSERT INTO `mrp_uno`.`persona_has_coche` (`numeroCompra`, `Persona_idPersona`, `Coche_idCoche`) VALUES ('21', '5', '11');

pero claro eso da error

Comment: A mi parecer deben ser dos insert (incluso más) cada uno finalizados (ponerle el punto y coma al final) mira en http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905900/mysql-transaction-roll-back-on-any-exception puede ser creando un StoreProcedure o Function (también puede ser) solo cuestión le pases los parámetros (datos a insertar) y así lo "manejas" como una instrucción atómica. Como no pusiste en que lenguajes lo estas haciendo la presente esta limitada a implementación en MySQL.

Comment: hmm me sale error cuando quiero crear el procedure, creo que mejor la are desde el lenguaje en donde voy a ligar a la base de datos jaja, gracias , igual tu respuesta es correcta, publicala como respuesta para darte la palomita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay muchas maneras de hacerlo, pero lo del procedimiento almacenado seria ideal porque se guardaria la consulta dentro de la Cache de Mysql, y esto ahorraria espacio tiempo :)

Podrias hacer algo parecido a :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ALGO(IN info tipo, IN info1 tipo, IN info2 tipo)
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION;

   INSERT INTO TABLA VALUES(info, info1, info2);
   INSERT INTO TABLA1  VALUES(info, info1, info2);
   INSERT INTO TABLA2 VALUES(info, info1, info2);

END;
```

Lo anterior llenaria 3 tablas a la vez con 3 parametros pasados.. si cada tabla por ejemplo, se llenaria con parametros distintos bastaria con que aumentes el numero de parametros, y lo vayas rotando en cada INSERT en las tablas por ejemplo :

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE ALGO (IN info tipo, IN info1 tipo, IN info2 tipo, IN info3 tipo, IN info4 tipo, IN info5 tipo)
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO TABLA VALUES(info1, info2);
    INSERT INTO TABLA VALUES(info3, info4);
    INSERT INTO TABLA VALUES(info5, info1);

END;
```

Comment: a que te refieres con ALGO? puede poner lo que sea ahí? y también a que te refieres con info tipo, info1 tipo, info2 tipo? gracias

Answer (score 0):

El problema no es de realizar las dos acciones en una sola consulta sino de realizarlas en una sola transaccion.  El concepto de transacciones es que todo lo que se hace en una sola transacción es como si fuera simultaneo desde el punto de vista de otras transacciones.

Revise lo de SET TRANSACTION, COMMIT, y ROLLBACK.  No sé como funciona en Mysql, pero tiene que ser semejante a Oracle o Sql Server.